# Using Soap the get product details is very slow

Tags: product, product-attribute, soap-api-v2

I'm working on an offline cash register application.
I write this in C# and use the SOAPv2 API to get the products.
These products I save in a local SQLite database.
So far this is working well, but it is very slow.
Using `catalogProductList()` I can get all products in one call, this is great. But the returned product had very limited details, only Name and ProductId are useful.
So I need to call `catalogProductInfo()` for every product to get the needed attributes like Price, Barcode and Stock.

Every call takes about 25s so it takes 16 hours to get the details of all 2300 products.

I've been looking for a method that combines `catalogProductList()` and `catalogProductInfo()` to get my attributes in one call for all products, but so far I haven't found it.

Any advice to increase the performance?